# How to write a SQL to return a row if condition met, and return another row if not

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am stuck in writing a SQL query, the function is something like to return a student's latest formal exam score in a month, or latest mock exam score if there is no formal for a student.

For example, here is a table to keep exam scores, column 'mode' is for formal exam or mock exam.

```
name          class        mode      score   exam_time
Alice         Math         mock      92      2019-03-21 10:00:00
Alice         Math         formal    88      2019-03-18 10:00:00
Alice         Math         formal    95      2019-03-07 10:00:00
Alice         Science      mock      89      2019-03-13 14:00:00
Bob           Math         mock      96      2019-03-21 10:00:00
Bob           Math         formal    90      2019-03-18 10:00:00
Bob           Math         formal    95      2019-03-07 10:00:00
Bob           Science      mock      98      2019-03-13 14:00:00
```

Need to have query result as:

```
Alice    Math    formal    88     2019-03-18 10:00:00
Alice    Science mock      89     2019-03-13 14:00:00
Bob      Math    formal    90     2019-03-18 10:00:00
Bob      Science mock      98     2019-03-13 14:00:00
```

For Math, there are both formal and mock exam, so need to return the latest formal, for Science, there is mock only, so return the mock one.

Because of other considerations, need to achieve it in one SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should be "achieve"... //hammer myself

Comment: Would you [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55759133/edit) to fix it? `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight variation of Kaushik's approach.  `distinct on` is the way to go, but I would write the logic as:

```
select distinct on (name, class) t.*
from t 
order by name, class, (mode = 'formal') desc, exam_time desc;
```

`distinct on` returns one row for each set of values in the grouping (what is in the parentheses).  The row is the first row determined by the `order by`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the "distinct on" clause, it is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I prefer `DISTINCT ON` to get top record per group.  It has slightly  better performance.

```
select DISTINCT ON (name,class) t.*
   from  t ORDER BY name,class,
    case when mode = 'formal' 
  then 0 else 1 end,exam_time desc ;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6a864ceb8446aeb43ccc888bb08fb87d)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `row_number` here:

```
select name, class, mode, score, exam_time
from
(
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name, class
                                   order by case when mode = 'formal' then 0 else 1 end,
                                            date_trunc('month', exam_time) desc) rn
    from your_table t
) t
where rn = 1;
```

The partition logic used above with `row_number` places all formal records before all mock records.  This means that a mock record would only be returned if there were no such latest formal records at all.